# Android cannot connect to server

Tags: android, connection

I have a server with IP address: 46.4.39.14. This is main server for my application and I never have problem to connect to this server via desktops. But problem appears very often on mobiles, and what is more strange, not all mobiles.

The most mysterious thing is that, if I have a problem to connect to the server, I also cannot connect to my server via web browser on the device. The problem is with connection to only my server (other websites like google always works, so it's not internet connection problem).

In effect, my application is frozen for few minutes, after few minutes it start working again (for a while).

So, here is the list of devices with the problem:
 * nexus 5, android 4.4.4
 * htc wildfire, android 2.3.5
 * Huawei g5100-0200, android 4.1.1
 * Moto G, android 4.4.2

On this devices I never had the problem:
 * Tablet asus ME173X, android 4.2.2
 * Galaxy tab 2 7.0, android 4.2.1
 * Sony Xperia T, 4.3
 * All desktops and emulators

I'm also pretty sure, that on Nexus 5 the problem appears only, when I'm connected to wifi, on HSDP it always worked.

In logcat there is nothing useful.

Any idea, what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are behind a proxy server which is denying connection to the address. 
Make sure your devices are properly configured to allow all apps to use the proxy server.

Comment: It's not proxy, we do not have one.